# how can access to the cell edited in tabulator with react

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I'm using react tabulator, displaying the data works perfectly, but I need to allow that the user can add tags in some cells, it's not clear to me how to achieve this because the docs only have [concise information about this](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.4#editable) and using the standard (vanilla js) library, I can't find a reacts way to achieve this

I'd like to connect the event with a redux dispatcher because I need to run an action when the user add or delete tags, but not sure if it's possible with this lib

I'd appreciate any help, guide, or clue about how can I achieve this, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-tabulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabulator) instead of tabulator